# Jenkins throwing error: jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds does not exist and probably cannot be created

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

i updated Jenkins from apt command line on Ubuntu,i did sudo apt upgrade jenkins immediately after update i am getting this:

```
jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds does not exist and 
probably cannot be created
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.checkRawBuildsDir(Jenkins.java:3085)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3009)
Caused: java.io.IOException
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3012)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:304)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:3104)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run 
(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1068)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1102)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:904)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Comment: I have tried to do a system for storing Jenkins backups with just only the config.xml and the /jobs. When trying to replace that files to restore from the backup the exactly same error is thrown. Any solution?

Comment: Didn't find any solution, i just had to reinstall Jenkins.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have experienced this when the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` directory had incorrect permissions or ownership. In my specific case I had rsync'ed jobs to a test server and forgot to update file ownership to match the user Jenkins runs under on the test system. Changing ownership to the correct user resolved the issue.

There are probably a number of reasons why this error can occur, but I would start by reviewing the files and directories under `$JENKINS_HOME` to verify that the user running the Jenkins process can read and write to them.

Answer (score 30):

Just found a solution. After update, Jenkins home dir had a mess of files with `ubuntu` and `jenkins` owners. I just changed ownership for all of them back to `jenkins`:

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME
```

Comment: Just to add in Ubuntu, your `$JENKINS_HOME` directory is often located at `/var/lib/jenkins`, so you could also run the command `sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins`.